# How can I make git bash `which` command work with windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, unix, git

If I type `which node` in git bash in Windows, then I get node's path, but when I type `which open`, it says it's not found.

The `open` program is in `PATH`, but not marked as executable since `chmod +x` doesn't work in windows.

I tried running `git update-index --chmod=+x` on the file but that doesn't fix `which` behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered running git via cygwin?

Comment: I didn't have a good experience with cygwin but it would probably work. Now that I know bash is comming to windows 10 I guess we'll just have to wait for it.